# problem with connection manager plugin in redcar

Tags: plugins, ftp, connection, redcar

I installed **Redcar** editor in my Ubuntu 10.10, but I have some problems with **Connection manager** plugin, I tried to connect to 3-4 different ftp servers, but i have the same error "***Error connecting:  doesn't seem to exist***", the remote path is empty.

Also i have an error "***500 Invalid PORT Command***", can i change the mode to passive, in this plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going wrong here, but I believe the remote path MUST be specified for the connection to work.

PS. Good places to ask this question would be

- the Redcar mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/redcar-editor
- the Redcar IRC channel: #redcar on irc.freenode.com
- the redcar bug tracker: http://redcar.lighthouseapp.com